# Pandas Aggregate concatenate other columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

This is the data set that I am using is as below:

```
data = [['2608 W SYLVESTER ST', 'PASCO', 'WA', 4304],
        ['61 W MESQUITE BLVD', 'MESQUITE', 'NV', 115000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 1000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 2000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 7000]])
```

The display of the dataframe:

```
          site_address         site_city         site_state   price
0  2608 W SYLVESTER ST             PASCO                 WA    4304
1   61 W MESQUITE BLVD          MESQUITE                 NV  115000
2       287 NW 3RD AVE          ESTACADA                 OR    1000
3       287 NW 3RD AVE          ESTACADA                 OR    2000
4       287 NW 3RD AVE          ESTACADA                 OR    7000
```

Need output as the following JSON structure:

```
[
   "sites": [
      {
        "location": "2608 W SYLVESTER ST, PASCO WA",
        "value": 4304
      },
      {
        "location": "61 W MESQUITE BLVD, MESQUITE NV",
        "value": 115000
      },
      {
        "location": "287 NW 3RD AVE, ESTACADA OR",
        "value": 10000
      }
]
```

Trying to use pandas, groupby & agg functionality:

```
df_grp = df.groupby('site_address', as_index=False).agg(**{
    'location': ** NEED HELP HERE **,
    'value': ('price', 'sum')
}).get(['location', 'value']).reset_index(drop=True)

result = json.loads(df_grp.to_json(orient='records'))

print(result)
```

Comment: Your example output is invalid; you have a list at the outer level when it seems you need a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = df.groupby(["site_address", "site_city", "site_state"]).sum().reset_index()
print(
    {
        "sites": df.apply(
            lambda x: {
                "location": f"{x['site_address']}, {x['site_city']} {x['site_state']}",
                "value": x["price"],
            },
            axis=1,
        ).to_list()
    }
)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "sites": [
        {"location": "2608 W SYLVESTER ST, PASCO WA", "value": 4304},
        {"location": "287 NW 3RD AVE, ESTACADA OR", "value": 10000},
        {"location": "61 W MESQUITE BLVD, MESQUITE NV", "value": 115000},
    ]
}
```

Prints:

```
{
    "sites": [
        {"location": "2608 W SYLVESTER ST PASCO WA", "value": 4304},
        {"location": "287 NW 3RD AVE ESTACADA OR", "value": 10000},
        {"location": "61 W MESQUITE BLVD MESQUITE NV", "value": 115000},
    ]
}
```

Comment: I expect this to be inefficient due to the `apply`. OP's solution was closer.

Comment: `agg("sum")` is equivalent to simply `sum()`. Also note: your address format isn't what OP actually asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_dict` prior to wrapping with a `sites` collection:

```py
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd

data = [['2608 W SYLVESTER ST', 'PASCO', 'WA', 4304],
        ['61 W MESQUITE BLVD', 'MESQUITE', 'NV', 115000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 1000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 2000],
        ['287 NW 3RD AVE', 'ESTACADA', 'OR', 7000]]
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        data=data, columns=['site_address', 'site_city', 'site_state', 'price'],
    )
    .groupby(['site_address', 'site_city', 'site_state'], as_index=False)
    .sum()
    .rename(columns={'price': 'value'})
)
df['location'] = df['site_address'] + ', ' + df['site_city'] + ' ' + df['site_state']

dict_data = {
    'sites': df[['location', 'value']].to_dict(orient='records'),
}
pprint(dict_data)
```

```
{'sites': [{'location': '2608 W SYLVESTER ST, PASCO WA', 'value': 4304},
           {'location': '287 NW 3RD AVE, ESTACADA OR', 'value': 10000},
           {'location': '61 W MESQUITE BLVD, MESQUITE NV', 'value': 115000}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
import json

d = df.groupby(['site_address', 'site_city', 'site_state'],
               as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
{'sites': 
    json.loads(d.assign(
        location = 
        (d['site_address'] + ', ' + d['site_city'] + ' ' + d['site_state']))
    .iloc[:,[-1, -2]].to_json(orient="records"))}
```

Output:

```
{'sites': [{'location': '2608 W SYLVESTER ST, PASCO WA', 'price': 4304},
  {'location': '61 W MESQUITE BLVD, MESQUITE NV', 'price': 115000},
  {'location': '287 NW 3RD AVE, ESTACADA OR', 'price': 10000}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

By explicit exposing groups and dicts construction:

```
result = {'sites': [{'location': (gr['site_address'] +', '+
                                  gr['site_city'] +' '+ gr['site_state']).values[0],
                     'value': gr['price'].sum()} for _, gr in
                    df.groupby(['site_address', 'site_city', 'site_state'])]}
```

---

```
{'sites': [{'location': '2608 W SYLVESTER ST, PASCO WA', 'value': 4304},
  {'location': '287 NW 3RD AVE, ESTACADA OR', 'value': 10000},
  {'location': '61 W MESQUITE BLVD, MESQUITE NV', 'value': 115000}]}
```